What permissions are needed for audio recording and audio storage in androidManifest Flutter?
I am developing a voice recorder app that needs to create and store audio files, when I try to request permission on android I get the following message

Permissions not granted

here is my function to record audio
  void startRecording() async {
    print('PERM REQUEST');
    Map<Permission, PermissionStatus> permissions = await [
      Permission.storage,
      Permission.microphone,
    ].request();

    bool
    permissionsGranted =
    permissions[Permission.storage]!.isGranted &&
        permissions[Permission.microphone]!.isGranted;

    if (permissionsGranted) {
      Directory appFolder = Directory(Paths.recording);
      bool appFolderExists = await appFolder.exists();
      if (!appFolderExists) {
        final created = await appFolder.create(recursive: true);
        print(created.path);
      }

      final filepath = '${Paths.recording}/${DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch}${RecorderConstants.fileExtention}';
      print(filepath);
      final config = RecordConfig();

      await _audioRecorder.start(config, path: filepath);

      emit(RecordOn());
    } else {
      print('Permissions not granted');
    }
  }

Permissions I use in manifest
    <uses-permission android:name=“android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE” android:maxSdkVersion=“32” />
    <uses-permission android:name=“android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE”/>
    <uses-permission android:name=“android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE”/>
    <uses-permission android:name=“android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES” />
    <uses-permission android:name=“android.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO” />
    <uses-permission android:name=“android.permission.READ_MEDIA_AUDIO” />

I tested on android 13 emulator, but on real devices the same problem, permission is not requested and recording does not work

use try catch block to check what is the error

In android Kotlin project I'm using

to access audio files on 13+ devices.
Not tried with flutter but I think you should check "Permission.storage" is actually providing above permission or not. this is different than storage permission

I think you add right dependencies.
There for you can add this internet permission.
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

There might be internet problem. You can ask for permission from user by using permission_handler package.
And use pub.dev packages like just_audio.
